# Can I use my power bank usb output to charge my laptop?

Tags: battery

so I have this power bank that has 3 outputs and one in which is a USB output that delivers 5v =~ 2 A!

The charging cord that came with the laptop has an USB end that connects to an adapter that delivers 20V =~ 3.25 A

I want to know if I take the USB end of the factory charging cord and if I plug it in my power bank will it decrease/burn the battery.

If you are curious of the specification
The laptop: Lenovo Yoga 900, it has the USB input.

Answer (score 5):

No - as you've stated the power bank falls far short of the power cable you have at 20V for charging, and can't provide close to the maximum amperage draw it may require of 3.25A (This is a maximum output of 65W, compared to the 10W maximum of your power bank.)

There is a very useful post [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/What-s-with-the-Yoga-3-Pro-power-adapter-it-s-a-USB-charger-too/td-p/1824182) which covers these points:

> How does it work?
>
> The special "fool proof" charging cord has two extra pins on the AC
>   adapter end and two extra pins on the Yoga 3 Pro end. The extra pins
>   only make a connection when the fool proof cord is plugged in to the
>   Lenovo charger and the Yoga 3 Pro. When a regular USB cord is plugged
>   into either the charger or the Yoga 3 Pro, it makes a regular USB
>   connection.
>
> **Can I charge the Yoga 3 Pro with any USB charger?**
>
> **No. The Yoga 3 Pro requires 2A at 20V, which is what the provided 40W
>   Lenovo AC adapter supplies.**
>
> Can I charge a USB device with the Yoga 3 Pro AC adapter?
>
> Absolutely. In addition to 2A at 20, the Yoga 3 Pro AC adapter
>   supplies 2A at 5.2V (10.4W), enough to charge a phone or tablet. Works
>   for iPad.

It looks like the charger port on your machine also doubles up as a USB port for power output (likely not data but it's possible), so you could charge other devices from the Yoga, but not the other way around.

Bring on USB-C... :)

Comment: But would it damage the laptop or is it generally safe to plug it in, even if nothing happened?

Comment: @comfreak Possibly damage the power bank if the laptop tried to draw too much from it. I doubt it would have enough power to damage the laptop but it's not impossible. More importantly, you'd need a USB A <-> USB A cable, which usually only exist with a very specific purpose which wouldn't be this, so that could also cause issues or potential damage. You could charge the power bank from the laptop though.

Comment: What if the laptop has a USB-C charging port and I would use a USB-A to USB-C cable on a standard USB-A powerbank (that has overload protection)?

Answer (score 1):

Not a chance. Your laptop needs something like 45W to 60W to charge. Your USB output supplies 10W maximum.

Comment: But what happens if you tried? Would it break the laptop or is it generally safe?